# performing background task on firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

**So the problem is following** - When `mProducts` is trying to get the products from the DB in `onDataChange()` call, then the fragment jumps to `onCreateView()`, sets the adapter with an empty array and after that performs the database task.
Am I missing something or what am I doing wrong?
Please point out the reason behind this weird behavior.

Thanks.

**Fragment class**

```
public class MainViewFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "MainViewFragment";
        private RecyclerView mView;
        private List<Product> mProducts;
        private DatabaseReference mRef;
        private MainViewAdapter mAdapter;

        public MainViewFragment() {

        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_view, container, false);
            mView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.mainViewRecyclerView);

//            mProducts = MockData.getProductData();
            mView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            mAdapter = new MainViewAdapter(mProducts,getActivity());
            mView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            return v;
        }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
        mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mProducts = Db.getDatabase(getActivity(),mRef).getProducts();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

**Database Class**

```
public class Db {
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private Context ctx;
    private static Db sDb;
    private List<Product> mProduct;

    public static Db getDatabase(Context ctx, DatabaseReference mRef) {
        if(sDb == null) {
            sDb = new Db(ctx,mRef);
        }
        return sDb;
    }

    private Db(Context ctx,DatabaseReference mRef) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mRef = mRef;
        this.mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        mProduct = new ArrayList<>();
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotIterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                Product product = null;
                while (dataSnapshotIterator.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshotIterator.next();
                    product = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(Product.class);
                    mProduct.add(product);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        return mProduct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `adapter class`, you should have a setter method for your dataset:

```
public void setData (Dataset dataset) {
  mDataset = dataset;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In the `onAttach`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mProducts = Db.getDatabase(getActivity(),mRef).getProducts();


                    mAdapter.setData(mProducts)

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: The mProduct is still returning null for some reason, tried with your code too.

Comment: you can set a debugger to ensure mProduct actually returns a value from firebase

Comment: it's returing null from `getProducts()` in the Db class.

Answer (score 0):

It could be this line that has the problem

```
product = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(Product.class);
```

is not giving the desired result, in which case, I usually desiarialize this way:
Lets say the Product class has two components - `name` and `price` which are String and int respectively, I'd have done it this way, if I had a constructor in the `Product` class with both components as parameters

```
String name = dataSnapshotChild.child("name").getValue(String.class);
int price= dataSnapshotChild.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
product = new Product(name, price);
mProduct.add(product);
```

where `"name"` and `"price"` are the node names in your database